# case, if/else statment to calculated out of spec value until within value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculated a value using case statement.  I know how to code a case statement but I need help in coding to determine how long the value was out of spec until it came back within specs.  For example if my out of spec value A = 6 and my specs are B = 1 to C = 4.  And at some point my value A comes back within my sepcs within B and C lets say A = 2.  lets say my value A started going out of spec at time 00:05:00 and came back within spec at time 00:15:00.  So how can I code this using case statement to know how long my value A was out of spec until it return back to within spec B to C.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: sample data + expected resultset + what have you tried sir?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly:

```
case
    when A between B and C then 'in specs'
    else 'out of specs'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can I do time calculation based on time.  Start time when my value A is out of spec until it got back within Spec.

Comment: @user3325894 After replying, I noticed that you have added time data. Can you show how data in your table looks, and what you want your output look like? Thanks.